# Xamarin FCM obtain token

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android

so I have read all the microsoft documentation I can get my hands on and looked through a lot of previous posts. I am obviously doing something stupid. I have an app that has an android project, an ios project and the main Forms project.

I can't run

```
var token = await FirebaseMessaging.Instance.GetToken();
```

You can't install FirebaseMessaging nuget to the Forms project because its not compatible with .netstandard 2.0. But you can't call it from the android project MainActivity onCreate because the app isn't initialized. All the examples show an app all being under one project. What am I missing? Where am I supposed to place this line of code?

Any help is appreciated. The microsoft docs not only have everything under 1 project, all their examples use deprecated version.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=windows

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should be mixing with how to use FirebaseMessage on Android apps and Form apps.

You need to set up the Notification in specific Xamarin.Android project and Xamarin.iOS project.

> You can't install FirebaseMessaging nuget to the Forms project because
> its not compatible with .netstandard 2.0.

For nuget [Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging), you can install it on android project.
If you try to install it to the main Forms project, there will be the error you said.

For **Xamarin.Android**:

You can check official document [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/firebase-cloud-messaging) and [Remote Notifications with Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=windows), there are step-by-step explanations of how to use Firebase Cloud Messaging to implement remote notifications  in a Xamarin.Android project.

For **Xamarin.Ios**:

You can use [Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging/#versions-body-tab) to send iOS push notification by FCM.

There are also steps here: [Firebase Cloud Messaging on iOS](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/blob/main/docs/Firebase/CloudMessaging/GettingStarted.md#about-firebase-cloud-messaging).

Firebase document for push notification to native app is here: [cloud-messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging).

**Note:**

You can also find many tutorials on internet, for example:

[Implement Push Notifications with Xamarin.Forms (Android) and FCM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7w2q2D6mR7g) and [Getting Started with Firebase Realtime Database and Xamarin.Forms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9tWcv2_HK9E).

The implementation will be a little different, but the process is much the same.